# ASPNET Return image from base64 in memory data and be cached by the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, base64, browser-cache

I am getting from the database images that are stored in base64 format for each user.
In my html I want to put something like this

```
  <img src="localhost:55790/getThumbnail/1">
```

This would make a call to my server return an image that would be cached by the browser so that on next page reload the call would not be executed again.
The blocking point I am encountering is on the server side, my current code that is not working:

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("getThumbnail/{userId}")]
    public ActionResult GetUserThumbnail(string userId)
    {


        var base64Image = _userService.GetUserThumbnail(userId);

        using (var imageStream = GenerateStreamFromString(base64Image))
        {
            return new FileStreamResult(imageStream, "image/jpeg");

        }
    }



    private static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            string base64 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(',') + 1);
            base64 = base64.Trim('\0');
            byte[] imageFileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(imageFileContent);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return  new MemoryStream();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A [Last-Modified](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and [Expires](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) headers will be useful for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return image through RESTful webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938234/return-image-through-restful-webservice)